# Setting OnClick on button in html table dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I'm creating a table dynamically, each row will contain a button and this button is going to call a function, each button will handle different parameters, for example,

```
    string Parameter1 = "MyValue";
    string Parameter2 = "MyOthervalue";

    HtmlInputButton input = new HtmlInputButton();
    input.ID = "Button1";
    input.Value = "button";
    input.Attributes.Add("onclick", "MyFunction(" + Parameter1 + "," + Parameter2 + ");");

    td = new HtmlTableCell();
    td.Align = "center";
    td.Controls.Add(input);
    tr.Cells.Add(td);
```

When user clicks the button I need to run MyFunction and then refresh the page to see the changes.

I know that maybe I could open a second page and send the parameters in the URL, but I'd like to use the code in the same page and then reload the page.

What's the best approach.

Thanks,

EDIT.

I was able to solve it in the following way:

```
    input = new Button();
    input.Text = "Click Me";
    input.CommandArgument = "3|Parameter3";
    input.Command += new CommandEventHandler(Button_Handler);

    td = new HtmlTableCell();
    td.Align = "center";
    td.Controls.Add(input);

    tr.Cells.Add(td);
    tbTable.Rows.Add(tr);



public void Button_Handler(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Button mybutton = (Button)sender;
    string[] Parameters = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('|');
    mybutton.Text = Parameters[0] + "-" + Parameters[1];
    //Call MyFunction(Parameters[0], Parameters[1]);

}
```

Comment: You want to postback in MyFunction on client side?

Answer (score 1):

I have a trick that you can use a hidden button and hidden field:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunction() {
        // do something
        document.getElementById("<%= hid.ClientID %>").value = "some value";

        // trigger hidden button click
        document.getElementById("<%= hiddenButton.ClientID %>").click();
    }
</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hid" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="hiddenButton" runat="server" OnClick="hiddenButton_Click" style="display:none" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void hiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // your business goes here
     string value = hid.Value;
}
```

Comment: Please notice that "some value" on MyFunction implementation should be a parameter  because the page is going to handle multiple records (probably hundreds) and each row in the table will contain a button so the idea is that MyFunction receives the value, different for each button, and process.

Answer (score 1):

If MyFunction is a javascript function, you can add `location.reload()` at the end of it in order to reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here I made some example code on how to add the clickevents dynamically:

```
  void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    HtmlInputButton NewButtonControl = new HtmlInputButton("submit");
    NewButtonControl.ID = "NewButtonControl";
    NewButtonControl.Value = "Click Me";

    // Create an EventHandler delegate for the method you want to handle the event
    // and then add it to the list of methods called when the event is raised.
    NewButtonControl.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Click);

    // Add the new HtmlInputButton control to the Controls collection of the
    // PlaceHolder control. 
    ControlContainer.Controls.Add(NewButtonControl);
  }

  void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Display a simple message. 
    Message.InnerHtml = "Thank you for clicking the button.";
  }
```

To refresh the page u could call a Javascript Function, something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function reloadPage()
  {
    window.location.reload()
  }
</script>
```

or try this:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

I hope it helps